# Site Switching Automatically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I have 4 Websites that I want to **loop** and showcase sort of like a slideshow but without any extra framework/added styling.

I just want to be able to go from Site 1 URL and then 5-10minutes later... it goes to Site 2, then 3 then 4 and then BACK to Site 1. In a never ending loop!

Is this possible and what is the best way to do this smoothly and efficiently??

Appreciate all the help guys.

Comment: You can do this in JavaScript. Not sure why you're against an extra framework (if it's a good one) though

Comment: I'm open for any suggestions! :) How exactly could I do this in javascript? [New to all this]

Comment: it depends on what you want. If you want a SLIDESHOW, you need javascript. If you want to really change URL, you need what is been posted here below. Can you clarify which of the 2 you want?

Answer (score 3):

PHP:

```
header("refresh: 600; url=yoursite.html");   // 600 seconds = 10 minutes
```

HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600;url=http://yoursite.com/">
```

Javascript:

```
function changeLocation() {
    window.location.href = "http://yoursite.com";
}

setTimeout (600000, changeLocation); // 600,000 milliseconds = 10 minutes
```

You can use any **one** of these (not all together) with a little logic to change the URL to the next one in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a meta refresh tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600;url=http://www.yournextsite.com/" />
```

on each website from one to another